# multiple sliders on a single page

Tags: web, slider, gallery

all. I have noticed that almost every single sample slider gallery out there uses IDs to identify their gallery div. Is there a way to easily change these to accept classes? Or what options do I have to make more than one slider on a page. I tried with many of them and they didn't work... Don't ask which ones because I have got no idea, after about the 15th one I didn't bother trying to remember what it was called.

So yeah, what sliders are there that are able to be on a single page more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. This is a Slider that I have actually used in my own website. This one doesn't use ID's but Classes. Trying to change all the ID's to classes in a slider that uses ID's could be a nightmare.
All you will do is just modify this so that there is two sliders on one page and that should do it.

http://plugins.jquery.com/jcarousel/

Hope this helps